# Clarification regarding validity of using data-URIs in CSS url()

Tags: css, standards, w3c-validation, data-uri

I'm writing a pre-processing component (in PHP) which, in certain contexts, rewrites external image file requests in CSS such as:

```
background-image: url('/my-folder/my-image.png');
```

as CSS-inlined **Data URIs**, such as:

```
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,[Base-64 Encoding Here]');
```

I've just read (with some surprise) over at **MDN**:

> In **CSS Level 1**, the `url()` functional notation described only true
>   URLs. In **CSS Level 2**, the definition of `url()` was extended to describe
>   any URI, such as a data-uri. **CSS Values and Units Level 3** returned to
>   the narrower, initial definition. Now, `url()` denotes only true `<url>`s.
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()

Really? This would seem to suggest that **Data-URIs** constitute an invalid value for `url()` in CSS Stylesheets (?)

But I can find nothing in:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/

that backs this up.

I was under the impression that a **Data-URI** is an entirely valid value for `url()` in CSS Stylesheets.

Can anyone clarify (ideally with an authoritative reference), please?

---

***N.B.*** The tag below reads `w3c-validation` - I recognise it should probably read `what-wg-validation`.

Comment: url() accept string so everything is valid from a CSS perspective then it may fall into 404 if the ressource is unvailable or nothing in the data-URI is badly written. Example of bad URI : (data:image/svg+xml;utf8,svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>) .. if your open it in the browser you will get an error

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif. Is **MDN** in error, then?

Comment: probably not wrong but it's a matter of langage and interpretation. Actually I don't understand what they mean by *true url*

Comment: I think they are distinguishing between actual `URLs` and other types of `URI`, such as a `data-URI`.

Comment: also if you check the last part with the specification table you can read *No significant change from CSS Level 1.* so they are explicitely saying that nothing was changed from the Level 1 to the Level 2 and also Level 3. a bit contradictory with what they said above

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, **MDN** is also reporting: _"`Data URLs` [...] were formerly known as "`data URIs`" until that name was retired by the WHATWG."_ (**Source:** _https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data:` URIs are actually valid URLs as per [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), don't worry, they are still allowed.

Not sure what this MDN article tried to imply when it says *"such as a data-uri"*, but I did edit it out to `URN` since it's actually [what happened in CSS 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/syndata.html#uri):

The specs did indeed extend the <url> notation to all URIs, by allowing [Uniform Resource Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) to be part of it too... I can't tell why they did this change, but it seems very weird to say the least, as I can't see how an URN could be any useful in a stylesheet... According to the specs wording, it seems its authors didn't quite know yet what it would be.

> URLs (Uniform Resource Locators, see [RFC1738] and [RFC1808]) provide the address of a resource on the Web. An expected new way of identifying resources is called URN (Uniform Resource Name). Together they are called URIs (Uniform Resource Identifiers, see [URI]). This specification uses the term URI.

---

Ps: Specs define it as "`data:` URLs" from the [fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#data-urls).